# Localizing Pattern Names

Tags: programming

When I want to define a function that uses a pattern, how should I localize the pattern name (i.e., `x_` localizing the symbol `x`)? I have traditionally used `Module` but Workbench seems to freak out at times that I have unused symbols. Is this just a bug in Workbench, or is there a proper way of doing this?

**Edit**

So I have been a bit vague in exactly what I mean. To clarify, suppose I make a function in Workbench as:

```
test[g_, f_] :=
    Module[{x},
        g /. f[x_] :> x
    ]
]
```

I will have an error on the `Module` line stating "the local variable 'x', is not used". Please note this example is just to give the bare minimum so that I get the Workbench error, and to illustrate what kind of localization I mean. That is I want to use a symbol for use in a pattern label, not as a variable.

Comment: In what way does Workbench "freak out"?

Comment: please see the expanded explanation.

Comment: Since you're using `RuleDelayed`, it is also localized and you don't have to write `Module[{x},...`

Comment: ahhh I didn't realize that. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Considering your update, I'd like to point out that `RuleDelayed` or `:>` also localizes its symbols, so there is no need to use `Module` or any other construct to force localize them. For example:

```
x = 1;
{1, 2, 3} /. x_?EvenQ :> "foo"

(* {1, "foo", 3} *)
```

Also, the documentation for `RuleDelayed` says this:

> `Module` and `With` do not affect local variables of `RuleDelayed`:
>
> ```
>  With[{x = 1}, a /. x_ :> x + 1]
>  (* 1 + a *)
> ```

Taking that example a bit further, you can see from the following that inside the scope of `RuleDelayed`, the definition of `x` in `Module` is disregarded (it really is `x$foo`), but outside its scope, the definition in `Module` kicks in:

```
Module[{x = b}, (a /. x_ :> x + 1) x]
(* (1 + a) b *)
```

Comment: I see you beat me while I was working on my edit.  Well played. :^)

Comment: Oh, yes; most certainly a planned chess move =) I first left it merely as a comment under the question, but then saw who wrote the incomplete answer below and just had to make my play :D I would say _checkmate_, but I don't have 37k...

Answer (score 6):

When you define a function using `:=` such as:

```
f[x_] := Sin[x] + 5
```

The `x` is automatically localized.  Every appeareance of `x` on the right-hand side of `:=` will be replaced with the argument of `f`, regardless of any value assigned to `` Global`x `` (since Global is the default context this just means e.g. `x = 1`).

You cannot however do something like this:

```
f[x_] := (x = Mod[x, 2]; x^2)

f[7]
```

> Set::setraw: Cannot assign to raw object 7. >>
>
> ```
> 49
> ```

This happens because as stated above `x = Mod[x, 2]` becomes `7 = Mod[7, 2]`.
Now `Module` is appropriate.${}{}{}$  We introduce a temporary symbol `t` and make assignment to that:

```
g[x_] := Module[{t}, t = Mod[x, 2]; t^2]

g[7]
```

> ```
> 1
> ```

---

Your updated question has an example that includes a third kind of localization: `RuleDelayed` (`:>`).

Much as the definition with `SetDelayed` (`:=`) when you create a rule such as `f[x_] :> x` the `x` is localized.  You therefore have three different localizing constructs in this code:

```
test[g_, f_] :=
    Module[{x},
        g /. f[x_] :> x
    ]
```

`g` and `f` by `:=`, *one* `x` by `Module`, and *another* `x` by `:>`.

Comment: @Fred thanks for the typo fix.  I hate this keyboard! :-p

Comment: Cool explanation of the symmetry with := thanks!