# Unexpected behavior of rule matching a pattern

Tags: evaluation, pattern-matching, replacement, faq

I am a beginner exploring the world of *Mathematica*. I expected the following code

```
T[6, 5, 4, 1, 2, 3] /. {T[a___, 1, b___] -> Length[List[b]]}
```

should return the value 2, rather than 1. Anyone could explain where I was wrong?

Comment: note that `T` is a bad choice of variable/function name. I suggest using names starting in lowercase letters, especially when using single letters. This avoids conflicts with built-ins (e.g. `N`, `D`...)

Comment: Related: [(13472)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13472/121), [(24860)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/24860/121), [(26619)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/26619/121)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is because the code `Length[List[b]]` is evaluated before the rule is applied. Using `RuleDelayed` rather than `Rule` would fix it:

`T[6, 5, 4, 1, 2, 3] /. {T[a___, 1, b___] :> Length[{b}]}`

Answer (score 10):

The function `Trace` can be helpful in diagnosing the problem.  The documentation says:

> Trace returns a set of nested lists. Each individual list corresponds to a single evaluation chain, which contains the sequence of forms found for a particular expression. The list has sublists which give the histories of subsidiary evaluations.

With your input:

```
Trace[
  T[6, 5, 4, 1, 2, 3] /. {T[a___, 1, b___] -> Length[List[b]]}
]
```

> ```
> {{{{Length[{b}],1},T[a___,1,b___]->1,T[a___,1,b___]->1},
>  {T[a___,1,b___]->1}},T[6,5,4,1,2,3]/.{T[a___,1,b___]->1},1}
> ```

Observe that the first evaluation chain is `{Length[{b}],1}` which clearly shows the problem.  Now compare the `Trace` when correctly using `RuleDelayed`:

```
Trace[
  T[6, 5, 4, 1, 2, 3] /. {T[a___, 1, b___] :> Length[List[b]]}
]
```

> ```
> {{{T[a___,1,b___]:>Length[{b}],T[a___,1,b___]:>Length[{b}]},
> {T[a___,1,b___]:>Length[{b}]}},T[6,5,4,1,2,3]/.
> {T[a___,1,b___]:>Length[{b}]},Length[{2,3}],2}
> ```

Comment: Thank you. This would be very helpful to understand the behavior of Mathematica.