# Why is ReplaceAll behaving like this?

Tags: pattern-matching, replacement, algebraic-manipulation, expression-manipulation

I'm learning to use the ReplaceAll function and I found the behavior of which is quite confusing.

---

For

```
Sqrt[f[x, y]] /. f[___] -> u
```

*Mathematica* returns

```
Sqrt[u]
```

However, if I replace f with `Plus`, i.e.

```
Sqrt[Plus[x, y]] /. Plus[___] -> u
```

instead of returning `Sqrt[u]`, *Mathematica* gives

```
u
```

---

For

```
a*Sqrt[x] /. Sqrt[_] -> u
```

*Mathematica* gives

```
a u
```

However, if the input is

```
a/Sqrt[x] /. Sqrt[_] -> u
```

Instead of returing a/u, *Mathematica* returns

```
a/Sqrt[x]
```

I'm really confused. Can anybody shed some light on the behavior of this function?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

#### Case #1

Observe:

```
"anything" /. Plus[___] -> "match"
```

> ```
> "match"
> ```

This is because `Plus[___]` evaluates to `___`, and `___` matches anything.  You can use `HoldPattern`:

```
Sqrt[Plus[x, y]] /. HoldPattern[Plus[___]] -> u
```

> ```
> Sqrt[u]
> ```

For this particular case you could also use the form `_Plus`, which matches any expression with head `Plus` but not `Plus` itself:

```
Sqrt[Plus[x, y]] /. _Plus -> u
```

> ```
> Sqrt[u]
> ```

#### Case #2

You must understand that pattern matching is done on something close to the `FullForm` of an expression, rather than the `StandardForm` output you normally see.  Let's look at your second problematic expression:

```
a/Sqrt[x] // FullForm
```

> ```
> Times[a,Power[x,Rational[-1,2]]]
> ```

As you can see, `Sqrt` is nowhere to be found.

You could prevent the evaluation of `Sqrt` on both the left-hand and right-hand sides:

```
Unevaluated[a/Sqrt[x]] /. HoldPattern[Sqrt[_]] -> u
```

> ```
> a/u
> ```

If you need to match for things that *appear* as Radicals in StandardForm you can use the methods described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5682963/618728).  An application of that might look like this:

```
ToBoxes[a/Sqrt[x]] /. _SqrtBox -> u // ToExpression
```

> ```
> a/u
> ```

Comment: Great answer. As an mma beginner myself, I learnt quite a bit from it. It also made me realise that using `Trace[]` can be helpful in seeing how mma evaluates rules and matches patterns. I suggest OP might give it a whirl too.

Comment: Thanks for the excellent answer. I find the 2nd solution on Case#2 very useful.

Comment: @Aky Thanks.  Indeed `Trace` is helpful, and I just recommended it [in an answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/22940/121) a few hours before this one, which is probably the only reason I did not mention it here.

Comment: @sy0116 I'm glad the answer is helpful to you.  Be aware that the `ToBoxes` method should only be used when necessary; if it is possible to accomplish your transformations using mathematical tools you should do so.  Operating on the box forms is a "last resort" as it were to manipulate what *Mathematica* shows you in StandardForm.  What *Mathematica* displays as a radical is somewhat arbitrary (or at least not readily apparent) and this is the only way to know to match exactly those cases.