# Replace doesn't replace the denominator

Tags: replacement, expression-manipulation

I have the following expression in Mathematica

```
    -((E^(2 - 2 Sqrt[(x[1] - x[2])^2]) (x[1] - x[2]))/Sqrt[(x[1] - 
   x[2])^2])
```

I want to replace anything of the form `Sqrt[t^2]` to `t`. I tried

```
-((E^(2 - 2 Sqrt[(x[1] - x[2])^2]) (x[1] - x[2]))/
  Sqrt[(x[1] - x[2])^2]) /. Sqrt[(t_)^2] -> t
```

But it just does the changes in the numerator and not in the denominator. What is that I am doing wrong here?
Thanks in advance!
-dbm

Comment: If you look at `FullForm` you'll see that you need `{Sqrt[(t_)^2] -> t, 1/Sqrt[t_^2] -> 1/t}`.

Comment: Yep, always use `FullForm[]` when a replacement doesn't work

Comment: It worked. But I don't understand the concept. Let's say, we want to replace E^(1 - x[1] + x[2]) to m[1,2]. Then the replacement doesn't change E^(2 - 2 (x[1] - x[2])) even thought it should be replaced by m[1,2]^2.

Comment: Because `FullForm[Sqrt[x]] == Power[x, Rational[1,2]]` while `FullForm[1/Sqrt[x]] == Power[x, Rational[-1,2]]` and therefore your pattern will not match.

Comment: This question has an answer here: [Pitfalls](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/29219#29219).  Related question: [Why is ReplaceAll behaving like this?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/22948/why-is-replaceall-behaving-like-this)

Answer (score 2):

When you have expressions you want to simplify in this way, I like to use `PowerExpand`.
Try

```
PowerExpand[-((E^(2 - 2 Sqrt[(x[1] - x[2])^2]) (x[1] - x[2]))/Sqrt[(x[1] - x[2])^2])]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `FullSimplify` with an assumption that the parameters are real-valued.

```
FullSimplify[-((E^(2 - 2 Sqrt[(x[1] - x[2])^2]) (x[1] - x[2]))/
             Sqrt[(x[1] - x[2])^2]), Assumptions->{x[1] > x[2] > 0}]

-E^(2 - 2 x[1] + 2 x[2])
```