# How do I use Replace All?

Tags: replacement, expression-manipulation

I have an expression:

```
a + b 2^(1/2) + (c + d 2^(1/2))*I
```

I want to replace each occurrence of `2^(1/2)` with `-2^(1/2)` and each occurrence of `I` with `-I`.  So I input:

```
a + b 2^(1/2) + (c + d 2^(1/2)) I /. {2^(1/2) -> -2^(1/2), I -> (-I)}
```

Mathematica returns:

```
(* a - Sqrt[2] b - I (c - Sqrt[2] d) *)
```

as I expected.

Now I want to make the same replacement again on this expression.  So I input:

```
a + b 2^(1/2) + (c + d 2^(1/2)) I /. {2^(1/2) -> -2^(1/2), 
  I -> (-I)}/. {2^(1/2) -> -2^(1/2), I -> (-I)}
```

Mathematica returns:

```
(*a + Sqrt[2] b - I (c + Sqrt[2] d) *)
```

I do not expect the MINUS sign in the middle of this expression.  It seems like it should be PLUS.?

Comment: Please format your code. Edit your post and apply the `{}` button where needed.

Comment: Perhaps `a + b 2^(1/2) + (c + d 2^(1/2)) I /. {2^(1/2) -> (-2)^(1/2), 
  I -> (-I)}`

Comment: I want to replace 2^(1/2) with -2^(1/2).

Comment: Here is a better way to pose my question.  If I input I /. I -> -I /. I -> -I     I would expect Mathematica to replace I with -I two times and then return I (positive) ?

Comment: This is a common problem with replacing complex numbers, and it is has been answered before. In the second replacement, try `Complex[0, -1] -> I`.

Comment: See [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/35435/replace-doesnt-replace-the-denominator) or [this other](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/84908/how-to-apply-replaceall-to-denominator) or [this third](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/39123/alternate-method-of-conjugation-using-replaceall)

Comment: more generally ` c_Complex:> Conjugate[c] `    ( which is in Daniels third link.. )