# Linear function on strings using UpValues

Tags: function-construction, pattern-matching, string-manipulation, linear-algebra

I have two functions `Sup` and `Sdown` that take a string of letters with allowed characters `"Z","W","P","H"` and returns a "sum" of strings with signs:

```
Sup[simple_String]:=
Block[{char=Characters[simple],z=0,w=0,n},
n=Count[char,"Z"|"P"];
Sum[
Which[
char[[i]]=="P",
z++;w++;0,
char[[i]]=="W",
w++;0,
char[[i]]=="Z",
z++;
Sigg[n,z,w]*StringJoin@@(Join[char[[;;i-1]],{"W"},char[[i+1;;]]]),
True,
0
],{i,Length[char]}
]
]
```

and

```
Sdown[simple_String]:=
Block[{char=Characters[simple],z=0,w=0,n},
n=Count[char,"Z"|"P"];
Sum[
Which[
char[[i]]=="P",
z++;w++;0,
char[[i]]=="Z",
z++;0,
char[[i]]=="W",
w++;
Sigg[n,z+1,w]*StringJoin@@(Join[char[[;;i-1]],{"Z"},char[[i+1;;]]]),
True,
0
],{i,Length[char]}
]
]
```

The sign is simply given by

```
Sigg[n_,z_,w_]:=If[EvenQ[n+w-z],1,-1]
```

As expected, this gives me i.e.

```
In[1]= Sdown["WPWPHH"]
Out[1]= -"WPZPHH" + "ZPWPHH"
```

Now, I want `Sup` and `Sdown` to be linear operators that can act on stuff like `Out[1]`, so I do this:

```
Sup/:Sup[Plus[x__]]:=Plus@@(Sup/@x)

Sup/:Sup[Times[i_Integer,s_String]]:=Expand[i*Sup[s]]
```

and the same for `Sdown`. But when I try to `Sup[Sdown["WPWPHH"]]` I get

```
In[2]= Sup[Sdown["WPWPHH"]]
Out[2]= 2 + "WPWPHH"
```

instead of `2"WPWPHH"` as  I would expect. The `FullForm` of `Out[1]` is `Plus[Times[-1,"WPZPHH"],"ZPWPHH"]` so when I do

```
In[3]= Plus @@ (Sup /@ {Times[-1, "WPZPHH"], "ZPWPHH"})
```

I get

```
Out[3]= 2 "WPWPHH"
```

like expected. What's going on here? Can you help me find the error? Also, if there is a better way of implementing this linearity, please let me know :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for a well-written question with complete code that made this reasonable to answer.  Welcome to Mathematica Stack Exchange. :-)

1. You do not need UpValues definitions here.  That would only apply if you were attempting to add a rule to e.g. `Plus` rather than `Sup`, yet your use of  [`TagSetDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TagSetDelayed.html) makes it clear that you are attaching the rule to `Sup`.
2. The major remaining issue is the pattern `Plus[x__]` which will not work; see: [Why is ReplaceAll behaving like this?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/22948/121)
3. In the pattern above, even if it did work, `x__` would be a sequence of expressions; you would need to wrap it in something before mapping, e.g. a `List`: `Plus @@ Sup /@ {x}`

Fortunately [`Map`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html) will work on expressions of arbitrary head therefore both problems can be avoided by matching the entire `Plus` object rather than the sequence.  Your solution is therefore:

```
Sup[x_Plus] := Sup /@ x
```

Now:

```
Sup[Sdown["WPWPHH"]]
```

> ```
> 2 "WPWPHH"
> ```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. I now have `Sup[x_Plus]:=Sup/@x` and `Sup[i_Integer*s_String]:=i*Sup[s]` and it works brilliantly.

Comment: @Marius Glad I could help.  Another formulation you might consider is: `Sup[i_Integer] := i; Sup[x : _[__]] := Sup /@ x`.  This maps `Sup` over any compound expression.  Atoms such as Strings or Integers are then individually handled.

Comment: Will there be any benefits (time, memory, ...) other than conceptual clarity in this case? In any case, thanks for the tip, it will surely help me with some of my other linear functions.

Comment: @Marius I don't know without testing.  On the surface I wouldn't expect any large performance difference but I have been surprised before.