# Tracing & Modifying a Function (Replace All)

Tags: replacement

For the function:

```
f[x_Plus] := Apply[Times, x]
f[a + b + c]
Out[]= abc
```

This is clear, as the **Times** is applied to the list with **Plus** head in f.

However, when giving the following:

```
g[x_] := x /. Plus[z___] -> Times[x]
g[a + b + c]
Out[]= a+b+c
```

It does not work the same as f. I tried to trace the function, but honestly I did not understand?

I tried to limit the application of the Times function to the inside of a list, as in:

```
g[x_] := x /. Plus[z___] /; x =!= List :> Times[x]
```

But it also did not work?

Could you please explain?

Comment: try `ClearAll[g];g[x_] := x /. Plus -> Times ;g[a + b + c]`?

Comment: It worked, could you plz explain why?

Comment: I mean, what was wrong with:
g[x_] := x /. Plus[z___] -> Times[x]

Comment: A1N,   `Times[a+b+c]`  is `a+b+c`; so with ` x = a+b+c`  as the argument of `g`, your rule  returns `a+b+c`.

Comment: The main problem is that `Plus[z___]` evaluates to `z___`. You need to include a HoldPattern in the LHS of your rule. You also have an issue where the RHS also evaluates, but you can fix that by using RuleDelayed instead of Rule.

Comment: @CarlWoll Thank you for your input .. I did try the following:
    j[x_] := x /. HoldPattern[Plus[z___]] :> Times[x]

Comment: @CarlWoll and it did not work. Could you plz further input. I did read the https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/22948/why-is-replaceall-behaving-like-this

Comment: You need to use z on the RHS as well, i.e., `HoldPattern[Plus[z___]] :> Times[z]`.