# Trouble with Replacements

Tags: replacement

I have the following line of code:

```
Plus @@ Table[p[x], {x, 0, 20}] /. p[x_] -> Boole[MemberQ[{0, 5}, x]]
```

The first part of this produces

```
p[0] + p[1] + p[2] + p[3] + p[4] + p[5] + p[6] + p[7] + p[8] + p[9] + p[10] +
p[11] + p[12] + p[13] + p[14] + p[15] + p[16] + p[17] + p[18] + p[19] + p[20]
```

What I thought the second part would do is to check each argument to p that occurs in this sum and replace `p[x]` with `1` if `x` is either `0` or `5` and with `0` if `x` is anything else. I thought, in short, the result would be 2. That's not, however, what I get. Instead *Mathematica* returns 0. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just change `->` with `:>` ;) (you want the function on the right to evaluate on substitution and not when defining the rule, this is called a delayed rule, you can find more on the help.)

Comment: D'oh! That did the trick. Thank you very much!

Comment: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/22917/unexpected-behavior-of-rule-matching-a-pattern could be of interest...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
    Clear[p];
p[x_] := Boole[MemberQ[{0, 5}, x]];
Plus @@ Table[p[x], {x, 0, 20}]
```

this:

```
Plus @@ Table[Boole[MemberQ[{0, 5}, x]], {x, 0, 20}]
```

this:

```
Plus @@ Table[p[x], {x, 0, 20}] /. 
     p[x_] -> UnitBox[x] + UnitBox[x - 5]
```

this:

```
Plus @@ Table[UnitBox[x] + UnitBox[x - 5], {x, 0, 20}]
```

or this:

```
Sum[UnitBox[x] + UnitBox[x - 5], {x, 0, 20}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly use `Sum[]` to directly generate your sum of `p[]`'s:

```
s = Sum[p[x], {x, 0, 20}];
```

From this, as you've been told, the use of `RuleDelayed[]` (`:>`) instead of `Rule[]` (`->`) is paramount here. Let me present a different way to do your replacement rule:

```
s /. p[x_] :> Boole[MatchQ[x, 0 | 5]]
   2
```

To explain: `Alternatives` (`|`) is a pattern that allows you to match any of its arguments; thus, `0 | 5` means "match either of `0` or `5`". You can then use `MatchQ[]` to test if `x` matches that pattern, and `Boole[]` then converts `True` and `False` into `0` and `1` respectively (i.e. an Iverson bracket).