# “Strange” behavior of Rule

Tags: replacement

According to the Help

> lhs->rhs evaluates rhs immediately.

How to understand the output of the following code?

```
ClearAll@x;
{1, 3.5} /. x_?IntegerQ -> {x}
```

Output is

```
{{1},3.5}
```

Since `Mathematica` evaluate the rhs **immediately**, I think the “correct” output should be this

```
{{x},3.5}
```

And of course, if x has `OwnValues`, the output will be changed.

```
x=”why”;
{1, 3.5} /. x_?IntegerQ -> {x}
```

Output is

```
{{"why"},3.5}
```

As expected.

In my opinion, the two examples expose the contradictions.

In the first one, `Rule` behaves like `RuleDelayed`; it relates the local x with global x. (The color of the two variables in front-end tells me this.) But in the second one, `Rule` makes a clear distinction between the local and global.
(There are also something similar between `Set` and `SetDelayed`)

Why does this happen? Did I misunderstand the mechanism?

### Update

What I'm really confusing is Why **sometimes** *Mathematica* **does not distinguish** the global x and the local x in Rule.

### Solution

As Aky has metioned in his comments and answer. The documentiation says,

> Symbols that occur as pattern names in *lhs* are treated as local to the rule. This is true when the symbols appear on the right-hand side of `/;` conditions in *lhs* , and when the symbols appear anywhere in *rhs* , even inside other scoping constructs.

So if `x` doesn't have `OwnValues`, then the `Head` of `x` is `Symbol` and the name of x is the same as pattern name, as the documentation said , *Mathematica* will treat the two 'x's as the same. If `x` has `OwnValues`,take `x=y` for example, (`Head` of `y` is also `Symbol`) Even if `x` (actually y) is `Symbol`, the "name" of x is y which is different from the pattern name.

So in the following case,

```
x=y;
{1,3.5}/.x_?IntegerQ->{x}
```

*Mathematica* will return `{{y},3.5}` not `{{1},3.5}`.

Thanks for everyone's attention:)

Comment: I changed `DownValues` to `OwnValues` as `x = "why"` sets an `OwnValue` not a `DownValue`.

Comment: X=”why”;x="why";
ClearAll@x;
{1, 3.5} /. x_?IntegerQ :> {x}

Comment: @rcollyer Thanks for the correction:)

Comment: @HyperGroups I know `:>` will behave as expected, but I just want to figure out the mechanism of `->`.

Comment: here, ->,:>generate the same result, x is not a x itself. x is a a element of pattern.

{1,3.5}/._Integer->xxxx
gives {xxxx,3.5}

x=what
{1,3.5}/.x_?IntegerQ->{x}
{{what},3.5}

{1,3.5}/.x_?IntegerQ:>{x}
{{1},3.5}

Comment: @HyperGroups I know that the x in `x_:>{x}` stand for the same thing. And I also understand the output if a value has been set to x. What I'm really confusing is Why _Mathemaitca_ will not distinguish the global x and the local x in **Rule** (not in `RuleDelayed`).

Comment: I'm not sure whether my explanation is right or whether it really explains the issue, but since the rhs of the rule is evaluated immediately, if there's no global rule for x (as in your first example), then rhs simply evaluates to itself and you're still left with x_?IntegerQ->x, the x on the rhs is the "same" as the one on lhs in the sense that it's the name given to the pattern object (otherwise how would you apply a replacement on a match?)

Comment: As the documentation says, "Symbols that occur as pattern names in lhs are treated as local to the rule." So the x is left as part of the rule (assuming that on the rhs it didn't first evaluate to something else, due to a global rule)

Comment: @Aky WO....I really should have carefully read the documentation from the beginning to the end. I think the problem is solved. Once we set a value to the golbal x,(x="why" for instance.) the head of x is not Symbol (in this case `String`) with name x anymore. This explain the second situation. If x remains x itself, the local x and global are treated to be the "same".

Comment: @luyuwuli, glad I could help

Comment: Somehow an `x` became an `X` in the `X="why"`.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau If `x` doesn't have `OwnValues`, then the `Head` of `x` is `Symbol` **and** the name of `x` is the same as pattern name, as the documentation said , _Mathematica_ will treat the two 'x's as the same. If `x` has `OwnValues`,take x=y for example, (Head of y is also `Symbol`)Even if x (actually y) is `Symbol`, the "name" of `x` is y which is different from the pattern name. In this case (`x=y;{1,3.5}/.x_?IntegerQ->{x}`), _Mathematica_ will return `{{y},3.5}` not `{{1},3.5}`.

Comment: @luyuwuli I believe DanielLichblau is referring to the typo in your second example; you've used uppercase 'x' (i.e. 'X') instead of lowercase, in the second example

Comment: @Aky I remember the x is lowercase when I first posted. That's strange. I'll edit the post

Comment: @Aky Maybe It's the auto-correction of my text editor change x to uppercase. I first write in the editor then paste on the website. Next time I'll write on the website directly.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I don't think there's a contradiction.

The documentation for `Rule` says

> Symbols that occur as pattern names in lhs are treated as local to the rule.

and as you've already pointed out,

> lhs -> rhs evaluates rhs immediately

In

```
ClearAll@x;
{1, 3.5} /. x_?IntegerQ -> {x}
```

the rule's rhs evaluates first, but there's no global rule associated with `x`, so the rule remains as `x_?IntegerQ -> {x}`, and the `x` everywhere in the rule is local to it.

In

```
x = "why";
{1, 3.5} /. x_?IntegerQ -> {x}
```

the rule's rhs evaluates to "why", and the rule becomes `x_?IntegerQ ->{"why"}`.

Comment: Yes, it's my carelessness. Thank you:)

Answer (score 8):

Perhaps it will seem clearer if the `FullForm` of the rule is examined.  In the first example below, we see that the value of `x` is the RHS of the rule.  So we should expect any integer to be replaced by `{2}`.

```
x = 2;
x_?IntegerQ -> {x} // FullForm
```

> ```
> Rule[PatternTest[Pattern[x, Blank[]], IntegerQ], List[2]]
> ```

Here, if we clear `x`, the RHS of the rule is `{x}`.  As @Aky pointed out in a comment, the documentation implies that in this rule the symbol `x` will represent the pattern match.  So we should expect any integer to be replaced by a list containing that integer.

```
Clear[x];
x_?IntegerQ -> {x} // FullForm
```

> ```
> Rule[PatternTest[Pattern[x, Blank[]], IntegerQ], List[x]]
> ```

One might wish to compare the above with `RuleDelayed`.  Even if `x` has an ownvalue, the RHS is `{x}`.  So this rule will behave like the previous one.

```
x = 2;
x_?IntegerQ :> {x} // FullForm
```

> ```
> RuleDelayed[PatternTest[Pattern[x, Blank[]], IntegerQ], List[x]]
> ```

Comment: Than you very much. It's my carelessness. Next time, I will carefully read the documentation before post my question. Since Aky has pointed it out in the comment first and also posted the answer. I'll accept his. (Both of you post your answers almost at the same time. At that moment, I was writing the comment.)

Comment: That's fine.  I thought perhaps Aky was not going to post an answer, so I impatiently went ahead :), having time on my hands at present.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why it works that way, and you have the same issue with f[x_]={x}. You will find code [here](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/425/) that defines new operators that work like  x_?IntegerQ->{X}  and  f[x_]={x}  except the new operators do what you expected.

Comment: Aky's comment (and many others' including mime) has solved the issue. I'll edit my post to include the answer in the end. BTW, thank you for the link, I'll study that:)

Answer (score 0):

Note that your first example is not contradictory with the immediate evaluation of the rhs.
For example, if you try :

```
ClearAll[x, y]
x = y
{1, 3.5} /. y_?IntegerQ -> {x}
```

you get {{1}, 3.5}.

This means that the rhs is really evaluated

Comment: I don't think this solve my confusion. Since the color of the local "y" is different from golbal "y". I think _Mathematica_ should **not** build bridge between the two 'y's. I mean I would rather get {{y}, 3.5} not {{1},3.5}.

Comment: agree it doesn't explain everything. Hope someone will go further.