# Why is head evaluation inconsistent in pattern replacement?

Tags: pattern-matching, string-manipulation, head

I noticed the following unexpected result:

```
In[90]:= "foo" /. x_String -> Head[x]

Out[90]= Symbol
```

Why is it that `Head[x]` doesn't return `String`? I would assume that since the pattern matched on a `String` head, the right hand side of the rule should see the same thing. Furthermore, the following expression gives the same result (assuming `foo` is undefined):

```
In[103]:= foo /. x_Symbol -> Head[x]

Out[103]= Symbol
```

How does one distinguish strings from symbols in the replacement part of a rule in this kind of situation?

Comment: You should use `RuleDelayed`: `"foo" /. x_String :> Head[x]`. Othewise, the r.h.s of your rule is computed before the match, when `x` is still a symbol, not bound to anything.

Comment: OK, I see how that works. How would you, though, with an eager (`->`) rule determine the "stringiness" of a particular symbol (i.e. the fact that it's quoted)? BTW, why don't you make this an answer?

Comment: Ok, I did as you requested. If you read the explanation carefully, it should answer your second question. One thing you should realize is that `x` has no connection to the string `"foo"` whatsoever, until the rule application happens.

Comment: I feel that this could be marked as a duplicate of one of the existing Q&A's about `Rule` vs `RuleDelayed`, perhaps [(22917)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/22917/121) or
[(24860)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/24860/121).

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I was trying to find such past discussions, since also suspected there were, but failed. And I agree with you that it would better serve us as a part of the pitfalls discussion, but have exhausted my available time for today - and for the pitfall post, I'd have to generalize a bit, and look also into those other posts, to take good pieces from those. Will do that when I get a moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Short answer

You should use `RuleDelayed`:

```
"foo" /. x_String :> Head[x]
```

Othewise, the r.h.s of your rule is computed before the match, when `x` is still a symbol, not bound to anything.

### Longer answer

Let's enumerate the main steps the main evaluator goes through, when evaluating your original code.

#### The case of `Rule`

- The head `ReplaceAll` is evaluated (to itself, trivially). Evaluation then goes to the elements (arguments of `ReplaceAll`), left to right.
- The first argument, `"foo"`, is trivially evaluated to itself
- The second argument, `Rule[x_String, Head[x]]` is evaluated

  - The head `Rule` is trivially evaluated.
  - Both of its arguments are evaluated, since `Rule` does not hold arguments

    - `x_String` is evaluated to itself
    - `Head[x]` is evaluated to `Symbol`, since at this time, in your case, `x` was not assigned any value. If it was, `Head[x]` would have evaluated to the head of that value.
- Finally, the internal `DownValues` for `ReplaceAll` are allowed to fire, "on the way up" in the recursive evaluation procedure. By this time, the rule you want to apply, is

  ```
  x_String -> Symbol
  ```

  And thus the result.

#### The case of `RuleDelayed`

- The head `ReplaceAll` is evaluated (to itself, trivially). Evaluation then goes to the elements (arguments of `ReplaceAll`), left to right.
- The first argument, `"foo"`, is trivially evaluated to itself
- The second argument, `RuleDelayed[x_String, Head[x]]` is evaluated

  - The head `RuleDelayed` is trivially evaluated.
  - Arguments of `RuleDelayed` start to evaluate from left to right. *However*,  `RuleDelayed` is `HoldRest`, and that is important here.

    - `x_String` is evaluated to itself
    - `Head[x]` is ***not evaluated*** at this time, due to the `HoldRest` attribute of enclosing `RuleDelayed`.
- The internal `DownValues` for `ReplaceAll` are allowed to fire, "on the way up" in the recursive evaluation procedure. By this time, the rule you want to apply, is

  ```
  x_String :> Head[x]
  ```

  Now, `ReplaceAll` is in the position to bind the value of `x` on the r.h.s. with the result found during the pattern-matching of the pattern on the l.h.s. against your expression (`"foo"` in this case). This results in a new expression `Head["foo"]`
- Finally, `Head["foo"]` evaluates to `String`.

#### Can we get the right result with `Rule`?

To answer your specific question in comments, it also should be clear from the above discussion, that  *generally*  one should use `RuleDelayed` to get the right result, instead of `Rule`.

One thing you can do, if you insist on using `Rule`, is the following:

```
"foo" /. Unevaluated[x_String -> Head[x]]

(* String *)
```

This works in this case, but note that in this approach, `x_String` does not evaluate either. This is Ok here, but it is important to note the difference.

### Summary

There are just a few things one needs to remember about `Rule` vs `RuleDelayed`:

- Use `Rule`, if you either

  - Do want the r.h.s. to evaluate *before* the pattern matching / replacement happens
  - Don't care, because for example the r.h.s of the rule is a constant expression, not containing any variables
- Use `RuleDelayed` in the majority of cases, when you have pattern variables on both sides of the rule.

So in general, when your patterns contain variables,  it is `RuleDelayed` you  typically want to use, not `Rule`.

Comment: You have my vote, as usual, but I think this might serve the community better filed under the Pitfalls post.  We certainly have multiple questions originating from the same problem but the nature of these makes them hard to search for.  (I only found two to link above though I know there are more.)

Comment: @Mr. Wizard, I believe this is the second or third question of this sort I've seen in the past two or so weeks.