# Confusion over blank sequence in pattern matching

Tags: pattern-matching

My overall goal was to produce a list of heads used in a graphics output.

For an example I used:

```
rp3D = FullForm[RevolutionPlot3D[{2 + Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}]];
```

and then

```
graphicsList = 
 Union[Flatten[rp3D //. f_[x__] /; UnsameQ[f, List] -> {f, x}]]
```

Union places all of the numerical values first. All I have to do is remove those elements and my goal is achieved.

I attempted to remove the numerical values using patterns and rules and found myself in my usual state of confusion and failure.

To resolve this I simplified the problem.

```
fakeList = {1, 2, 3, a, b, c}
```

I attempted to remove the numbers using:

```
fakeList /. {x__?NumericQ, z__} -> {z}
{2, 3, a, b, c}
```

I expected it to grab the first three numbers but it only gets the first one. I was unable to decipher from the documentation whether BlankSequence is greedy (apparently not).

I was unable to produce a pattern test or condition to cause "z" to be non-numeric.

Help and explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: See [`Longest`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Longest.html)

Comment: `graphicsList = DeleteCases[Union[Flatten[rp3D //. f_[x__] /; UnsameQ[f, List] -> {f, x}]], _?NumericQ]`  or  `graphicsList = Union[Flatten[rp3D //. f_[x__] /; UnsameQ[f, List] -> {f, x}]] /. _?NumericQ :> Sequence[]`

Comment: I think pattern matching is greedy from the *end* of the list, so z__ matches as much as it can first, leaving x__ to match the 1. (That might not be quite right, but it has been my working principle up to now.) That's why the recommendation for using Longest[x__?NumericQ] in a previous comment.

Comment: @march graphicsList /. {Longest[x__?NumericQ], z__} -> {z} works perfectly. Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Shortest.html) states:

> If no explicit `Shortest` or `Longest` is given, ordinary expression patterns are normally effectively assumed to be `Shortest[p]`, while string patterns are assumed to be `Longest[p]`.

Leftmost elements in a sequence of patterns have first priority, and explicit uses of `Shortest` have priority over this implicit shortest behavior.

Also make sure you use [`RuleDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RuleDelayed.html) when working with named patterns on the right hand side unless you specifically know you want otherwise; see [Unexpected behavior of rule matching a pattern](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/22917/121).

```
{1, 2, 3, a, b, c} /. {Longest[__?NumericQ], z__}  :> {z}
{1, 2, 3, a, b, c} /. {__?NumericQ, Shortest[z__]} :> {z}
{1, 2, 3, a, b, c} /. {__, z__?(Not@*NumericQ)}    :> {z}
```

> ```
> {a, b, c}
>
> {a, b, c}
>
> {a, b, c}
> ```

Comment: @"Mr.Wizard" Thank you. That explanation is crystal clear as to why I was experiencing the result that confused me. Thank you also for the tip on using RuleDelayed.

Comment: @"Mr.Wizard" The PatternTest to make Z non numeric was very nice. I have always skipped over reading about Composition. I viewed it as being esoteric and impractical. Nice to see it working in a real world example. I hope to add Composition to my limited Mathematica tool box.

Comment: @JackLaVigne Glad I could help!  By the way beware of [(1699)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1699/121) -- the precedence of the `?` operator is highly unusual.  (For more about operator precedence perhaps read [(30425)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/30425/121).)