# Rule for derivatives

Tags: pattern-matching, replacement, rule, calculus-and-analysis

I have a differential equation of the form

$$f'(x)=g(x,f(x))$$

(where $g$ is has a known explicit form, *e.g.* $x f(x)$) and I have an expression which contains several derivatives of $f$. I want to use the differential equation to substitute all the derivatives in order to leave the expression as a function of $f(x)$ and $x$ only. For this purpose I have written the following rule:

```
ruleDerF = Derivative[n_][f][x_] -> D[x f[x], {x, n - 1}];
```

This works ok, e.g.,

```
f''[x] /. ruleDerF

(*f[x] + x f'[x]*)
```

and

```
f''[x] //. ruleDerF

(*f[x] + x^2 f[x]*)
```

The problem appears when I want to apply this rule when the function is evaluated for a value of $x$. If I try naively to apply this rule on $f(1)$ it gives an obvious error:

```
f''[1] /. ruleDerF

General::ivar: 1 is not a valid variable. >>

(* \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \({1, 1}\)]\(f[1]\)\) *)
```

This is obvious because you cannot derive wrt 1. So I tried to redefine the rule in the following way,

```
ruleDerF = Derivative[n_][f][x_] -> (D[y f[y], {y, n - 1}]/.y:>x);
```

believing that the delayed rule would cause to first perform the derivation wrt the symbolic variable `y` and then evaluate it to the introduced value, but it doesn't work this way (I get the same result as before).

Any idea that could help me?

Comment: Perhaps this should be marked as a duplicate of [(22917)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/22917/121) or one of the [many questions it is linked to](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/22917?lq=1)?

Comment: You might be interested in `DifferentialRoot[]`: `f = DifferentialRoot[Function[{y, x}, {y'[x] == x y[x], y[0] == 0}]]` and then look at `f''` for example. This will only work if you have given initial conditions and your DEs are linear.

Comment: Are you trying to prevent the derivative `D[y f[y], {y,n-1}]` from being carried out every time the rule is applied?  One can imagine applying this rule thousands of times for a fairly complicated `f[x]`, and wishing for the derivative to only be carried out once, and stored thereafter.  This is how I interpreted in intent behind `->` rather than `:>`, but perhaps it's simply a mistake that I'm overthinking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define your rule as a function:

```
ruleDerF = (# /. Module[{x}, 
   Derivative[n_][f][var_] :> (D[x f[x], {x, n - 1}] /. x -> var)
])&

f''[x] // ruleDerF
```

> ```
> f[x] + x Derivative[1][f][x]
> ```

```
 FixedPoint[ruleDerF, f''[x]]
```

> ```
> f[x] + x^2 f[x]
> ```

```
FixedPoint[ruleDerF, f''[1]]
```

> ```
> 2 f[1]
> ```

(*havent tested heavily*)

Comment: Shouldn't you localize `x`?  And wouldn't mentioning `RuleDelayed` be useful to the OP?

Comment: Maybe I'm crazy but at first blush it looks like he is using `:>` and `->` backward, or at least haphazardly.  Certainly you changed `->` to `:>` following `Derivative[n_][f][x_]`.

Comment: Trying to understand why this solution works I realized that defining the rule as `Derivative[n_][f][x_] :> (D[y f[y], {y, n - 1}]/.y->x)` does the job. The only thing left, as mentioned, is to localize the dummy variable `y`.

Comment: Finally I have opted for defining the rule as `Derivative[n_][f][var_] :> 
 Module[{x}, (D[x f[x], {x, n - 1}] /. x -> var)]`. I will mark the answer as right because it's equivalent. Thank you for your insights.

Comment: @DavidPravos no need to accept so quickly, I will add more explanations later. Some things are needed and some may be confusing, like using `FixedPoint`, which isn't necessary.

Comment: @Kuba What value does placing the rule inside a function add here, seeing as the OP asked for a rule?

Comment: @jjc385 thanks for reminding me of that question, I will rephrase it because I used things that makes this answer confusing.