# Merging two variables in one

Tags: pattern-matching, string-manipulation, variable-definitions

I was looking for a way of, given two variables called A and B, obtaining a new variable called AB. My idea was doing simple pattern matching, e.g.

```
A B/.x_ y_->ToString[x]<>ToString[y]
```

But this rule outputs `xy` instead of the desired `AB`. Is there a way of obtaining the desired output? Thank you for your time.

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you for the effective, quick response. If you post an answer I will give it as the accepted one :)

Comment: `A B /. x_ y_ :> ToString[x] <> ToString[y]` gives `"AB"` -- see http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/22917/121

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want to replace the literal variables `A` and `B` then you cannot use the pattern `x_ y_`, as this will match **any** product of two expressions. Is this what you want?

```
expr = a^2 + a b + b^2;
expr /. a b -> Symbol[ToString[a]<>ToString[b]]
```

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I wanted, thank you so much!

Comment: This does not make sense to me.  If you are not using patterns on the LHS why not just use `/. a b -> ab`?  @Alex same question to you if this really is the solution you want.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, of course the `Symbol[ToString[` is completely superfluous in this case. I just included it to show the OP that it can still be used but with a different LHS, but I see that it may be more confusing than clarifying.

Answer (score 2):

Another option

```
ClearAll[x,A,B,c,d,y,x]
expr = a A B c d y x
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
expr /. Times[x___, A, B, y___] :> x AB y
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Notice that this changes  `a A B c d y x` and `A a B c d y x` to same result, which is `a AB c d x y`. But this also happens with the above answer as well, so I assume this is what you wanted.

If on the other hand, you wanted to handle `A a B` differently from `a A B` in terms of if `A B` should be combined or not, then this should be made clear in the question.