# Rule vs RuleDelayed in the context of StringReverse

Tags: pattern-matching, syntax, rule

```
{"test", 3} /. s_String :> StringReverse[s]
{"test", 3} /. s_String -> StringReverse[s]
```

The second line gives the error:

> StringReverse: String expected at position 1 in StringReverse[s]

Question: why does it give the error with Rule, but not RuleDelayed?

EDIT: I noticed that `{3, 4} /. s_ -> Sin[s] // N` works without error. What is the difference?

Comment: Try evaluating `StringReverse[s]` on its own, without `s` having a value.

Comment: @Szabolcs I think my question is different; what I didn't understand was that the rhs of a rule is calculated first... so the line is not evaluated strictly from left to right...

Comment: There is no difference at all in this regard between `Set` and `Rule`.  In fact the LHS *is* evaluated first, as you assumed. But LHS of the rule is only `s_String`. The `/.` and what comes to the left of that is *not* part of the rule.   It's the reverse: The rule is part of the `/.`. Look at the full form: `ReplaceAll[{"test", 3}, Rule[s_String, StringReverse[s]]]`.

Comment: Since neither `Rule` nor `ReplaceAll` have any (relevant) `Hold*` attributes, [the standard evaluation sequence](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/EvaluationOfExpressionsOverview.html) is followed: 1. left to right, starting with the head and continuing with arguments.  2. then apply definitions associated with the head.  This means that `StringReverse[s]` gets evaluated *before* `ReplaceAll` has a chance to do anything with it.

Comment: @Szabolcs Why does this `{3, 4} /. x_ -> Sin[x] // N` work without error then? Here `Sin[x]` is evaluated before Mathematica knows `x` is a real number...

Comment: I've marked this topic a duplicate of [22917](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/22917/5478), let me know if you disagree.

Comment: This goes back to my first comment ... try evaluating `Sin[x]` on its own ... Is there an error?  Do the same with `StringReverse[x]` now.  Is there an error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't use `RuleDelayed`, `StringReverse` is executed before the rest of the function. And because it expects a string as argument (and not the symbol `s`) it complains and goes on strike.

You can see this with

```
TracePrint[{"test", 3} /. s_String -> StringReverse[s], _StringReverse]
```

And also with

```
{"test", 3} /. s_String -> StringReverse["ab"]
```

> {"ba", 3}

Comment: Why does it actually work in this case: `{3, 4} /. x_ -> Sin[x] // N` ? `x` is not know to be a real number yet here is well...

Comment: @Gambit, once more: when in doubt as to how something gets evaluated, wrap the expression in `Hold[]` and look at the `FullForm[]`: `FullForm[Hold[{3, 4} /. x_ -> Sin[x] // N]]`. You will then see that the replacement is done before the sines are seen by `N[]`.

Comment: @GambitSquared, Also, note that `StringReverse` requires a string or list of strings as an argument,otherwise it will generate the message you see. `Sin` can accept numeric or symbolic arguments.