# Why is the variable x not locally scope in the StringExpression?

Tags: string-manipulation, scoping, localsymbol

```
 Clear[x]
 StringCases["abcadcacb","a"~~x_~~"c"->x]
```

> ```
> {b,d}
> ```

```
 x=99;
 StringCases["abcadcacb","a"~~x_~~"c"->x]
```

> ```
> {99,99}
> ```

This fails even if x is local in a Module

```
Module[{x}, StringCases["abcadcacb", "a" ~~ x_ ~~ "c" -> x]]
```

Comment: I mean, *most* functions in *Mathematica* don't scope their variables. But you can use `RuleDelayed` (`:>`) instead of `Rule` (`->`) to fix this problem. Also, I'm not *entirely* sure why `Module` doesn't work in this case, but `Block` does, for good reasons: `Block`'s *purpose* is to locally scope variables that have definitions elsewhere.

Comment: By the way, the problem isn't that `x` is not locally scoped in the string expression, because it is. Evaluate `"x"` after `x=99` to see that this is true. The problem is that the `x` at the end of the `Rule` is not locally scoped.

Comment: @march Thanks. What really confused me was that Module didn't work to scope that variable.  I will use Block as you suggested.

Comment: @march I guess you should alway RuleDelayed in this case, because, in general, you will never know when you are changing a value inadvertently. Maybe the Mathematica documentation should use RuleDelayed in the examples instead of Rule.

Comment: For me, I almost always use `RuleDelayed` when replacing expression via patterns.  I only use `Rule` when I'm replacing an expression with something that doesn't depend on that pattern. There are use cases for both, but `RuleDelayed` allows you to circumvent these scoping problems for the most part, and you can always inject an expression into the right-hand side of a delayed rule using the `With` scoping construct. Still, the implementation of `Module` here is a little wired to me.

Answer (score 1):

Why `x_->x` causes problems is explained in:

[Unexpected behavior of rule matching a pattern](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/22917/5478)

Shortly, use `:>`.

Why `Module` fails to help? While `Rule` is not a scoping construct it is considered one by `Module`. Which means `x` inside will not be scoped by `Module` if `x_` appears in a left hand side of rule.:

```
Module[{x},
  Hold @ Column @ {
    Rule[x_, x]
  , RuleDelayed[x_, x]
  , Module[{x}, x]
  , DirectedEdge[x_, x]
  , foo[x_, x]
  , Rule[y_, y x]}
 ]
```

[image]

Relevant part of docs:

> Symbols that occur as pattern names in lhs are treated as local to the rule. This is true when the symbols appear on the right-hand side of /; conditions in lhs, and when the symbols appear anywhere in rhs, even inside other scoping constructs.
>
> ref/Rule/Details

About issues with nested scoping constructs you can take a look at:

[Enforcing correct variable bindings and avoiding renamings for conflicting variables in nested scoping constructs](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20766/5478)

which also explains the last example with `y_->y x`.

Also related:

[Unexpected behavior of rule matching a pattern](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/22917/5478)